# How to pass reference of an object to arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm not sure how to pass the reference of profile that I create to the arrayList that should be made up from references to other profiles

English not my first language so I'm sorry that my question is not the example of informativeness.

I've got the assignment to write a class that creates profile for imaginative social media. One profile consists from: first name, last name, date of birth made by three different integers, town, country, nationality, array of interests, an array or ArrayList of friends represented as
references to Profile.

So, I create arraylist and adder

```
ArrayList<Profile> friendList= new ArrayList<> ();

void addFriend(Profile p) {
        friendList.add(p);
    }
Profile getFriend (int i) {
        return friendList.get(i);
    }
```

But I'm not I'm not sure how to get an index that is possible to use when I'm putting the profile in a friendList

Comment: What makes a `Profile` unique? Maybe a combination of names and DOB.  Create an `equals` method on your `Profile` based upon this, then you can simply do a [indexof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)  Or you can just loop through your list looking for the element you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can override equals method of Profile and then call `friendList.indexOf(profile)` which will give the index of that profile.

for more you can check into this link: [How to Find an Element in a List with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java)